# How to exclude same rows in SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I have this script that creates a table and store Sale Order information. The scenario behind it is that once and Item is added into Sale Order it's `Status` is `'A'` means `Add`. Later somehow customer wants that item to be removed so we add a new row with same details but `Status` as `'D'` means `Delete`.
Now I want to get only active Sale Order Items which should not include that item which was `Added` and then `Removed` from Order.
Here's my script.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL](
    [ORDER_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ITEM_NAME] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [QUANTITY] [int] NULL,
    [PRICE] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL] ([ORDER_NUMBER], [ITEM_NAME], [QUANTITY], [PRICE], [Status]) VALUES (N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Double Bed', 5, CAST(70000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL] ([ORDER_NUMBER], [ITEM_NAME], [QUANTITY], [PRICE], [Status]) VALUES (N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Sofa', 5, CAST(10000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL] ([ORDER_NUMBER], [ITEM_NAME], [QUANTITY], [PRICE], [Status]) VALUES (N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Dining Table', 1, CAST(50000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL] ([ORDER_NUMBER], [ITEM_NAME], [QUANTITY], [PRICE], [Status]) VALUES (N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Sofa', 5, CAST(10000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'D')   
GO
```

The expected output I'm looking for should be something like this as Item `'Sofa'` was cancelled from Order.

```
ORDER_NUMBER    ITEM_NAME       QTY PRICE
SO-100-ORD-19   Dining Table    1   50000
SO-100-ORD-19   Double Bed      5   70000
```

Query:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ITEM_NAME, QUANTITY, PRICE FROM [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL]
WHERE Status <> 'D'
GROUP BY ORDER_NUMBER, ITEM_NAME, QUANTITY, PRICE
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You've asked enough questions to know that you should post your attempts as well.

Comment: Seems like an awkward design data wise - what happens if someone inserts a `D` record that doesn't match in all details an existing `A` record? (Either in it's entirety or just e.g. based on the price)

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT SD.ORDER_NUMBER,
       SD.ITEM_NAME,
       SD.QUANTITY,
       SD.PRICE
FROM dbo.[SALE_DETAIL] SD
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.[SALE_DETAIL] e
                  WHERE e.ORDER_NUMBER = SD.ORDER_NUMBER
                    AND e.ITEM_NAME = SD.ITEM_NAME
                    AND e.[Status] = 'D');
```

Answer (score 2):

Logically, the set-based answer is to use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
declare @SALE_DETAIL table([ORDER_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ITEM_NAME] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [QUANTITY] [int] NULL,[PRICE] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,[Status] [varchar](50) NULL)
INSERT @SALE_DETAIL ([ORDER_NUMBER], [ITEM_NAME], [QUANTITY], [PRICE], [Status]) VALUES
(N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Double Bed', 5, CAST(70000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'A'),
(N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Sofa', 5, CAST(10000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'A'),
(N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Dining Table', 1, CAST(50000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'A'),
(N'SO-100-ORD-19', N'Sofa', 5, CAST(10000 AS Numeric(18, 0)), N'D')

select Order_number,Item_name,Quantity,Price
from @SALE_DETAIL
where Status = 'A'
except
select Order_number,Item_name,Quantity,Price
from @SALE_DETAIL
where Status = 'D'
```

Which produces the results you've asked for. However, note that for whetever reason, this often seems to perform poorly in practice, in which case something like [Larnu's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143635/15498) may be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

In words: select all *'A'*-records for which no matching *'D'*-record exists.

In SQL:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER, ITEM_NAME, QUANTITY, PRICE
FROM [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL] X
WHERE Status = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM [dbo].[SALE_DETAIL] Y
  WHERE Y.Status       = 'D'
  AND   Y.ORDER_NUMBER = X.ORDER_NUMBER
  AND   Y.ITEM_NAME    = X.ITEM_NAME
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try get expected result using `not in` operator as shown below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ORDER_NUMBER, A.ITEM_NAME,A.QUANTITY, A.PRICE, A.Status
FROM SALE_DETAIL A
    where A.ITEM_NAME not in (select s.ITEM_NAME from SALE_DETAIL s
    where s.[Status] = 'D')
```

The output is as shown below

```
ORDER_NUMBER    ITEM_NAME   QUANTITY    PRICE   Status
------------------------------------------------------
SO-100-ORD-19   Dining Table    1       50000   A       
SO-100-ORD-19   Double Bed      5       70000   A
```

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/DKSM30921)